# I've installed lsd in Ubuntu 19.04. But when I run lsd command, it shows command not found

Tags: command-line, 19.04, snap, paths

```
Command 'lsd' is available in '/snap/bin/lsd'
The command could not be located because '/snap/bin' is not
 included in the PATH environment variable.
lsd: command not found
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: See this: https://github.com/Peltoche/lsd/issues/79

Answer (score 1):

Edit your /home/yourname/.bashrc and add the following line:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/snap/bin/"
```

Then restart your Terminal and you should be able to run `lsd`.

Comment: It shows: "cannot access '.': Permission denied (os error 13)"

Comment: @SahilAnsari did you replace "yourname" with your user name?

Comment: Ofcourse, I did.